# jQuery .change text input after checkbox .change

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a bit of code that calculates a price and quantity once a check box is selected but I'm having trouble implementing the change to the quantity field if it's changed from the default of 1 without unchecking and rechecking the checkbox and refiring the checkbox change.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20%">Item</td>
    <td width="10%">Price</td>
    <td width="10%">Quantity</td>
    <td width="10%">Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td >
        <input type="checkbox" name="Extras" value="id" />
    </td>
    <td>Test Item 1</td>
    <td class="price">12.50</td>
    <td><input name="qty" class="quantity" value="1"></td>
    <td class="total"></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td >
        <input type="checkbox" name="Extras" value="id" />
    </td>
    <td>Test item 2</td>
    <td class="price">20</td>
    <td><input name="qty" class="quantity" value="1"></td>
    <td class="total"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        parentRow = $this.closest('tr'),
        totalCell = parentRow.find('.total');

    if ($this.prop('checked') === true) {
        var price = parseFloat(parentRow.find('.price').html());
        var quantity = parseFloat(parentRow.find('.quantity').val(
           // assuming I'd need a $('input:text').change(function() { 
           // etc at this point but all i've tried doesn't work
           ));
        totalCell.text(price * quantity)
    }
    else totalCell.text('')
});

});
```

Hope that makes sense

Comment: explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: I'd like it to be able to automatically update the total when the quantity is changed without unchecking and rechecking the checkbox. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vNg9v/8/
Thx!

Comment: @ankur Sorry... Should've clarified before I posted it. Got it answered :)

Comment: @WadeH please see my answer below. you only need to change your js that's it no need to change html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you don't have an event tied to your quantity textbox.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KtMRL/) or the code below:

```
$('.quantity').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        parentRow = $this.closest('tr'),
        totalCell = parentRow.find('.total');
        checkBox = parentRow.find('input:checkbox');  
    if (checkBox.prop('checked') === true) {
        var price = parseFloat(parentRow.find('.price').html());
        var quantity = parseFloat($this.val());
        totalCell.text(price * quantity)
    }
    else totalCell.text('')
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Simple... Thought for sure I had to add it within the checkbox element.

Answer (score 0):

change your jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            parentRow = $this.closest('tr'),
            totalCell = parentRow.find('.total');

        if ($this.prop('checked') === true || parentRow.find('input:checkbox').prop('checked') == true) {
            var price = parseFloat(parentRow.find('.price').html());
            var quantity = parseFloat(parentRow.find('.quantity').val());
            totalCell.text(price * quantity)
        }
        else totalCell.text('')
    });


});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vNg9v/9/)

Answer (score 0):

There were small problems that I have fixed. go through it and let me know what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var crntSelection = $(this),
        parentRow = crntSelection.closest('tr'),
        totalCell = parentRow.find('.total');

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('checje');
        var price = parseFloat(parentRow.find('.price').html());
        var quantity = parseFloat(parentRow.find('.quantity').val(
           // assuming I'd need a $('input:text').change(function() { 
           // etc at this point but all i've tried doesn't work
           ));
        alert(price);
        alert(quantity);
        totalCell.html(price * quantity)
    }
    else totalCell.text('')
});

});​
```